# How to check if an element exist on the dom after an event with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have read this article about conditional testing, but still dont understand it.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Error-Recovery

I have this case where, when i enter a value on an input and then submit it, sometimes, depending on the value i enter, it shows/renders aother element on the DOM.

So i need to do something like:

"after an event(e.g. submit the value on the input), check if there is certain element on the dom, and then do something, else do something else"

From what i read in the cypresss docs, they keep saying the dom should be always the same, that the element that appears depending on the value we enter on the input, should already be there.

But thats not the case and is a normal behaviour in modern sites.

How can i do this? Otherways when i try to ´get´ the element, if its not there, it crashes.

How do people normally manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend chaining it on an upper element in the DOM tree which is always rendered, something like:

```
    cy.get('.app__inner').then($app => {
        if ($app.find('.your_element').is(':visible')) {

            // fill the logic here
        } else {

            // fill the logic here
        }
    });
```